# Is it possible to set `oracle.net.encryption_client` property purely in JDBC connection URL?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Is it possible to set `oracle.net.encryption_client` property purely in JDBC connection URL?

I can see that the property can be set via properties parameter of `DriverManager.getConnection(url, props)`. But is it at all possible to pass the parameters in the URL string, specifically, for Oracle JDBC driver with Thin client?

If it is not possible to set this using the JDBC URL, is it possible to set this property globally for Java application?

Answer (score 1):

(1) Yes, you can set it as a system property. -Doracle.net.encryption-client=...

(2) You can set it as a connection property as well. Check out the
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL
Also, check the sample [DataSourceSample.java](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceSample.java) to see how to pass the connection properties.

(3) We do allow properties as part of the URL from 19c version. But, this property is not allowed in the URL. Check out the [EasyConnect Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-843F6EC2-EDFD-4A88-98DE-B45E1CEADC0E) for more details.

Comment: Using command line parameters will work for us. But using the JDBC URL string would be preferable. When you say "we do allow some properties as part of the URL from 19c version," does that mean only those listed in the docs linked above?

Comment: Sorry, all properties are allowed as part of URL. I corrected my answer.

Comment: @Nirmala, it would be really helpful it you could provide an example of how to specify the oracle.net.encryption_client and oracle.net.encryption_types_client in the URL.

Comment: try this: jdbc:oracle:thin:@[[protocol:]//]
    host1[,host12,host13][:port1][,host2:port2]/service_name[:server][/instance_name]
    [?[parameter-name1=parameter-value1][&parameter-name2=parameter-value2],...]