# Oracle JDBC Thin: enforce network encryption

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

The question is how to enforce encryption using the Oracle JDBC Thin driver and by specifying this solely in the URL?

It is understood that we need to set the Oracle Net parameter `oracle.net.encryption_client` to `required`. (ref [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/client-side-security.html#GUID-D04ABE6D-2529-4C60-9EDD-3A966B43ECFB))

For reference: We are currently specifying the Oracle JDBC URL in the TNS format, for example:

```
DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = myora1.corp.net)(PORT = 1521))
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = myora2.corp.net)(PORT = 1521)))
   (FAILOVER=ON)
   (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME = foobar))
```

which translates to the following JDBC URL string:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = myora1.corp.net)(PORT = 1521))(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = myora2.corp.net)(PORT = 1521)))(FAILOVER=ON)(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME = foobar)))
```

Before you answer you should know the following:

1. We cannot use Properties as this is a third-party application. All we can set is the URL string.
2. We cannot use optimistic encryption (the default in Oracle). For regulatory reasons we need to guarantee that we obtain an encrypted connection. And we need to enforce this from the client-side. (we need to protect ourselves from a potential misconfiguration on the server-side)
3. By 'encryption' we mean using Oracle's build-in encryption method, termed *Oracle Advanced Security*, rather than TLS. The latter is certainly also an option but is a lot more involved (certificate circus) and Oracle Advanced Security has been deemed as "good enough" by our security specialists.
4. We currently use the TNS descriptor format in the URL. If another format allows to specify the said parameter, `encryption_client`, then fine to use that URL format instead .. as long as it allows us to specify the same, for example the ADDRESS_LIST.
5. We can replace the JDBC driver in use, meaning we have the freedom to use latest version if so required.

I see this question asked before on SO but without ever receiving a proper answer.

Any answer should ideally contain pointers to Oracle's documentation.

Comment: `When using the JDBC OCI driver, set parameters as you would in any Oracle client situation. When using the Thin driver, set parameters through a Java properties object.` I don't see a way to do it with thin without a properties.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez. Well, there's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62882515/1504556) which seems to be from an Oracle employee (my guess: [SO nirmala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4393594/nirmala) = [Nirmala Sundarappa](https://blogs.oracle.com/author/nirmala-sundarappa)). I find that particular answer rather confusing but it indicates to me that there's potentially more possibilities than what can be read from the official docs. And that others have had the request that everything must be configurable from URL alone.

Comment: you are totally right. Documentation sucks. Have you tried this format ? `jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host)(PORT=5521))(CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=servicename))(Security=(ENCRYPTION_LEVEL=REQUIRED)))`

Comment: I can't test it on my own :(

Comment: @RobertoHernandez. This is very difficult to test as the default is (with the servers I have access to) that you would get an encrypted connection anyway. I have tried adding
`(Security=(ENCRYPTION_LEVEL=bogus))` just to see if it would react. It didn't. Btw: where did you come up with that idea?  Docs pointer, pls.  :-)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL

Comment: @RobertoHernandez. Thx. It is in the v21 Javadoc, not in the v18 as you've linked.

Comment: Bingo. I made it work by adding what you suggested. However, it does require v21 of the JDBC driver. It will object to `(Security=(ENCRYPTION_LEVEL=bogus))` (as expected because `bogus` is not a valid value) when using v21 but on lower versions that parameter will simply silently be ignored.

Comment: GREAT!! Can I provide an answer that you can accept, therefore other people can benefit from it ?

Comment: The assumption that an encrypted connection does not work below v21 because an unsupported value will not cause an error is kind of weird. Even v12 already had this property. Why should Oracle add a property that won't work until nine years later? I think Oracle simply added error handling in v21 that prevents bogus values to this property.

Comment: Then how to make it work with OJDBC 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comments, starting with v21 of the Oracle JDBC Driver you can use the `Security` option for the `thin` method as follows:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=servicename))(Security=(ENCRYPTION_LEVEL=REQUIRED)))
```

Thereby you don't need a properties and you can embed in the connection string the encryption level desired.

You can furthermore restrict the *encryption algorithm* for added security, for example:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=servicename))(Security=(ENCRYPTION_CLIENT=REQUIRED)(ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT=AES256)))
```

With this we are saying that the connection MUST be encrypted and it MUST be encrypted with the (currently) strongest algorithm available.

See:

[Encryption Level JDBC String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL)

[Encryption Types JDBC String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_TYPES)