# How to make encrypted connection to Oracle using Java JDBC Library (OJDBC 7)?

Tags: java, oracle, encryption, wildfly, ojdbc

My company is implementing encryption on all database connections. I am using Wildfly and Java Project. We also use straight JDBC connections.

Services are connecting to Oracle DB for saving data or fetching data.

My connection string looks like:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ora01.man.cosng.net:1521/int_prod
```

There is no encryption thing passed. Java code also has nothing related to encryption.

Is Java driver encrypted by default? (ojdbc7.jar), or do we need to send extra properties defined in this article (but this require changes in 140 projects) -> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/clntsec.htm#EHAFHEIG

Or any other idea?

Also Wildfly has following settings: anything you can suggest here which is straightforward:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle JDBC Thin: enforce network encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69644315/oracle-jdbc-thin-enforce-network-encryption)

Comment: @stdunbar: No i am using  OJDBC7

Comment: OJDBC7 only tells us it is for Java 7, it provides zero information about the actual version of the OJDBC driver you're using. However, the fact you're using an OJDBC7 driver suggests your project is seriously out-of-date on its dependencies, as recent versions of the OJDBC driver don't even offer a Java 7 variant of the driver.